# Ordenação de tags H dentro de uma página

Tags: html, seo, html-tags

Gostaria de saber se há problemas em informar mais que uma tag H1 dentro de uma página, mais em relação ao SEO, se o Google condena esse tipo de ação.

E também, se há problema de eu informar primeiramente uma tag H2 e depois uma H1, nessa ordem mesmo.

Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é importante utilizar apenas uma tag `<h1>`, porque esta tag indica o **principal assunto** abordado em sua página, o foco principal da página em questão.

As demais heading tags como `<h2><h3><h4><h5>` são como sub-títulos da sua página, e falando de SEO, seria como **palavras chave complementares**.

Exemplos de Heading Tags:

```
<h1>Buffet Infantil da Carochinha</h1>
<h2>Festas temáticas</h2>
<h3>Festas do Barney</h3>
<h3>Festas dos Angry Birds</h3>
<h3>Festa da galinha pintadinha</h3>
<h2>Venha visitar a casa na Vila Olímpia - São Paulo</h2>
<h3>Ponto de referência</h3>
<h3>Estacionamento</h3>
```

Note que o conteúdo das heading tags inicia da mais relevante `<h1>` para a menos relevante `<h3>`, aonde `<h1>` é o assunto principal do site, e as demais, assuntos relacionados ao conteúdo principal da `<h1>` em questão, que sim, podem ser repetidas, porque o foco principal é mantido, esclarecendo para o usuário, o que a página apresenta principalmente, e este tópico, sim, com subtítulos relacionados ao título, que podem ser sim, mais de um.

Fontes:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/pt-BR//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

http://www.seomarketing.com.br/heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-seo.php

Answer (score 2):

Questão de hierarquia a tag `h1` tem poder visível *[1]* maior que a tag `h2` e assim por diante. O uso correto é: `h1` para titulo e os demais para indicar subtitulo.

O único problema de utiliza-los fora de ordem é que para o *SEO* a informação contida pode deixar de ser relevante.

*[1] - Não visivelmente para o cliente*

Answer (score 0):

Não, não há problemas em usar mais que uma *tag* `H1`. Convém não exagerar, como é lógico, mas se precisares de usar mais uma ou duas *tag's* `H1` não há qualquer problema, dito por um Eng. da Google:

[Link de vídeo](http://youtu.be/GIn5qJKU8VM)

Comment: Isso contraria muita coisa que já li por aí. Será que isso ainda é válido? levando em conta que o vídeo é de 2009.

Comment: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/pt-BR//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf
Documento base para SEO do google, ele não diz "Não use", mas fala claramente sobre "usar corretamente e evitar repetição". Até porque `<h1>` é o foco principal da página, então, não há porque dividir o foco principal em 2, faz mais sentido ter um único `<h1>` e talvez 2 `<h2>` com subtítulos principais.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu disse, não há problemas em usar mais que um mas convém evitar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar uma `H1` para cada página. Use a tag para o título principal da página, e não para itens diversos. Para isto, use `OL`

Comment: Ao invés de OL, o ideal não seria usar `ul` e `li`?

Comment: Elas fazem quase a mesma coisa, só que `ol` cria listas ordenadas e `ul` desordenadas.